# Getting rid of the annoying Photoshop CS6 timeline

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Every time I open Photoshop, here it is, the annoying and obtuse timeline box. I hide it. I create my own workspace and save it. But every time I run Photoshop CS6 the timeline window is there. I close it, and open a file. Every time a file opens, the $&&%#$ window is back.

How do I get rid of this disgusting window?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your Photoshop preference folder (or at least move it temporarily).  It can be found in ~/Library/Preferences and named Adobe Photoshop CS6 Settings

Once it is gone, restart Photoshop.  It should be in a clean state.  Untick the Timeline in the Window menu and then close Photoshop.  Reopen it again and the Timeline window should not be visible (as well as when you create/open files).

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me on a single file, because I'd messed around with animation a little and then deleted it.

What I had to do in the end to stop the timeline opening every time I opened that file, was to copy everything into a new PSD.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to stop the Timeline window from opening every time you open your file, you must:

- select all your layers in the Layers Panel
- click on the options menu in the top right of the Layers Panel and select "Duplicate Layers..."
- Duplicate to a "New" document, save the new document
- Delete the old document with the timeline attached

That's it! This takes about 10 seconds.

Comment: You can again [Adobe CS6 Download](http://onesoftwares.com/adobe-photoshop-cs6-portable-free-download/) hope it will work properly.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get rid of the timeline go to the top menu and click "Windows" and then "Timeline".

Comment: You can again [Adobe CS6 Download](http://fileparrots.blogspot.com/2017/04/adobe-photoshop-cs6-portable-iso-3264.html) hope it will work properly.